# Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<android.app.Fragment>'

Tags: java, android, unchecked-cast

I am getting an unchecked cast warning and I am not sure if it is safe to suppress it.

I am putting an `ArrayList<Fragment>` inside a `Bundle`. This Bundle is then put in my Intent as following:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MySecondActivity.class);
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putSerializable("fragmentList",ArrayList<Fragment>);
mIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Then on my new activity (MySecondActivity) I am retrieving this data with the following code:

```
(ArrayList<Fragment>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fragmentList")
```

My compiler gives me the following warning:

> " Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to
>   'java.util.ArrayList' "

Everything is working fine though, am I right to say I can safely suppress it?

Thank you!

Comment: assuming you have complete control over the "fragmentList", yes.

Comment: A dynamic check whether the object is indeed an ArrayList and whether each element is indeed a Fragment is not very expensive. In case something *does* go wrong, this might give you a better diagnostic. (We all know good old Murphy ;-)

Comment: I do have complete control over the fragmentList indeed. I will try to do a dynamic check if each element is indeed a Fragment. If done, can I just simply suppress the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are not Serializable, same for ArrayLists of Fragments. So, `putSerializable` in this will not work, ever. even if they were serializable you would still need to use the method correctly. something like:

```
ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragmentList.add(foo);
...
myBundle.putSerializable("fragmentList", fragmentArrayList);  //not ArrayList<Fragment>
```

Instead try,

1. have `MySecondActivity` create these fragments you wanted to pass to it in the `onCreate`
2. Place the data classes you want to pass to `MySecondActivity` in the bundle for that intent, but implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) instead since it is a quicker/better than Serializable

For step two,  [here is a tutorial](http://blog.denevell.org/android-parcelable.html) about making your data classes implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

HTHs!!!

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing, did not post it because I thought it wouldn't make sense if you're not seeing my whole code. That's why I put the ArrayList <Fragment> there. I used Serializable for the sake of simplicity. I don't really need to send the data fast, however I will take a look at Parcelable.